# Make "x" number of copies based on user input in Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

everyone. I know this problem would be better solved with a different platform, but a batch file is all I have right now. Here is what I currently have:

```
@echo off
set Output="%USERPROFILE%\desktop"

echo NOTE: Do not use leading-zeros when entering month/day for study date and DOB
echo     -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

set /p TestNum=Enter the test number: 
set /p SeriesInstance=How many images are in this series?: 
set /p StudyDate=Enter the date (ex 1-1-2018) of the study: 
set /p StudyTime=Enter the time (ex 1448) of the study: 
set /p AccessionNumber=Enter the accession number: 
set /p ProcType=Enter the study type: 
set /p PhysName=Enter the referring physician's name: 
set /p StudyDesc=Enter a study description: 
set /p PtName1=Enter the patient's first name: 
set /p PtName2=Enter the patient's last name: 
set /p PtID=Enter the patient's ID (Last 4 of SSN,year,month,day - NO COMMAS): 
set /p PtDOB=Enter the patient's DOB (ex 1/1/1984): 
set /p PtGender=Enter the patient's gender (M or F): 

echo 0020000D   %TestNum% >> %Output%\%PtID%.txt
echo 0020000E   %SeriesInstance% >> %Output%\%PtID%.txt
echo 00080018   %SeriesInstance% >> %Output%\%PtID%.txt
echo 00080020   %StudyDate% >> %Output%\%PtID%.txt
echo 00080030   %StudyTime% >> %Output%\%PtID%.txt
echo 00080050   %AccessionNumber% >> %Output%\%PtID%.txt
echo 00080060   %ProcType% >> %Output%\%PtID%.txt
echo 00080090   %PhysName% >> %Output%\%PtID%.txt
echo 00081030   %StudyDesc% >> %Output%\%PtID%.txt
echo 00100010   %PtName2%,%PtName1% >> %Output%\%PtID%.txt
echo 00100020   %PtID% >> %Output%\%PtID%.txt
echo 00100030   %PtDOB% >> %Output%\%PtID%.txt
echo 00100040   %PtGender% >> %Output%\%PtID%.txt

echo.
echo File has been placed in %Output%
pause
```

What I am trying to do is, if a number greater than 1 is entered for SeriesInstance, I want the batch file to make that number of copies of the exact same file, with the only difference between the files being that the two lines that output SeriesInstance increase by 1, up until it reaches the SeriesInstance value.

Sorry if I am explaining that terribly :-\

I appreciate any help you can give!

Answer (score 2):

Since the files will have to have different names, I'll assume you want to append the sequence number to the file name, such as `%Output%\%PtID%_X.txt` where `X` is the sequence number.

In that case, you can simply use `for` to do a loop, something like:

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,%SeriesInstance%) do (
  (
    echo 0020000D   %TestNum%
    echo 0020000E   %%a
    echo 00080018   %%a
    echo 00080020   %StudyDate%
    rem rest of echo statements here
  ) >%Output%/%PtID%_%%a.txt
)
```

This snippet above also has the advantage of minimising the file open/append operations and ensuring no spaces are at the end of each line.

Comment: @paxdiablo: feel free to include that into your answer, so I can delete this answer

Comment: Cheers, Stephan. Since you came up with a substantial improvement on my answer, I'd prefer to incorporate them both into yours. It's not like I need the extra rep :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo and Stephan thank you both so much for your help. The batch file is working nicely and it saves some a lot of time when compared to manually creating these txt files, especially when there are man in a series!